# How to use the child event to Visible and Hide other controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a usercontrol that is my header and inside it, there is an event to close.

I used this header in mainc usercontrol.

```
        public static readonly RoutedEvent ClosedEvent =
                          EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Closed",
                                   RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MainHeaderView));

    public event RoutedEventHandler Closed
    {
        add { AddHandler(ClosedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ClosedEvent, value); }
    }


    private void buttonClose_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
         RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ClosedEvent));
    }
```

And mine has been used elsewhere.

```
   mainHeaderView.Closed += MainHeaderView_Closed;
private void MainHeaderView_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshGridFooter();
    }
```

Now I want to click to close usercontrol
Hide mine and Visible message control.

I have implemented the closure on the header side and use its event in the mine
But now I do not know how to use this event in the original form?

[image]

Comment: you shouldn't be able to use the same event in the parent form (it's against encapsulation principle), you can implement another event in the header control so the parent can listen to it, and fire it from inside the header control. But if all you need to do is to hide a global message box, it does not make so much sense to couple the messagebox with every control, it's better to use a different design, use a static method within the message box to show/hide itself instead.

Comment: if the control has a name you can use eventtriger and a visibility animation. Not the cleanest way to go about this tho...